# Akka: what is the reason of processing messages one at a time in an Actor?

Tags: scala, asynchronous, akka

It is said:

> Akka ensures that each instance of an actor runs in its own lightweight thread and that messages are processed one at a time.

Can you please explain what is the reason of processing messages one at a time in an Actor?

Answer (score 14):

This way we can guarantee thread safety inside an `Actor`.

Because an actor will only ever handle one message at any given time, we can guarantee that accessing the actor's local state is safe to access, even though the Actor itself may be switching Threads which it is executing on. Akka guarantees that the state written while handling message `M1` are visible to the Actor once it handles `M2`, even though it may now be running on a different thread (normally guaranteeing this kind of safety comes at a huge cost, Akka handles this for you).

It also originates from the original Actor model description, which is an concurrency abstraction, described as actors who can only one by one handle messages and respond to these by performing one of these actions: send other messages, change it's behaviour or create new actors.

Comment: I got you - it all comes from JMM. So, each actor is tied to its thread at a time. What about millions of actors on a single JVM and a few cores of CPU? The performance will degrade in this case greatly (context switches)!

Comment: "lightweight thread", emphatically not necessarily a concrete JVM thread. The akka runtime will handle such concerns.

Comment: Actors are not tied to a specific thread (that is, unless you specifically want so). They usually run on a fork-join thread pool, which distributes actor `receive`s execution to its threads. The default thread pool in Akka, AFAIK, sets the number of threads based on the number of physical cores in your machine.

Comment: Good point! Thus, no performance degradation, there's a fixed thread pool. Each thread gets assigned an actor's receive turns out. Where can I read about this in Akka in more details?

Comment: Exactly, great explanations guys. Akka reuses threads by keeping them running and always executing some actor's code if he has things to run - this way we can keep thread numbers low, and actor numbers in millions. Hope this helps!